# Matlab correlation between two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

Basically I have two matrices, something like this:

```
  > Matrix A (100 rows x 2 features)

  Height - Weight
  1.48      75
  1.55      65
  1.60      70
  etc...
```

And Matrix B (same dimension of Matrix A but with different values of course)

I would like to understand if there is some correlation between Matrix A and Matrix B, which strategy do you suggest me?

Comment: Are we talking about *the* statistical correlation? In that case, the only correlation I know works with random variables, not matrices with different (possibly dependent) variables. If not, what kind of connection between the matrices do you want to examine?

Comment: Another idea: Do you assume some relationship, say `Weight = a*Height` (like in a linear model) and want to compare if both matrices contain similar models, e.g. if `a` for matrix `A` roughly equals `a` for matrix B?

Comment: @Thilo: that could be an idea! Please note that for convenice I can create a single matrix... something like this: `HeightA-WeightA-HeightB-WeightB x 100 rows`

Comment: In that case I would suggest you looking at linear models, check the corresponding assumptions (e.g. does the plot Weight vs. Height look linear?) and then try to fit linear models (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Matlab can do this with the stats toolbox, if do do not have that one licenced, R is a great tool for that kind of questions.

Comment: @Thilo: what if i want to know the correlation between just one matrix? Something like this: http://www.socialresearchmethods.net/kb/statcorr.php can Matlab do it?  `corrcoef` returns an Array not a number

Comment: I don't understand what is "some correlation", you probably have something more exact in mind, right?

Comment: @Thilo There is a well developed (but not very well known) bit of theory in the field of multivariate analysis for obtaining the correlation between two matrices known as canonical correlations. I've written a short explanation of it in an answer to this question - and Matlab has a function in the stats toolbox that can do it.

Comment: The `corr([A, B])`, `corrcoef([A, B])` can calculate it. Maybe what you mean is that `A` and `B` are from different sources and you need to check their consistency? If this is the case, I suggest to generate a uniform grid of Height, interpolate on it Weight from both matrices, and calculate `corr(Weight_A, Weight_B)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concept you are looking for is known as [canonical correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation). It is a well developed bit of theory in the field of multivariate analysis. Essentially, the idea is to find a linear combination of the columns in your first matrix and a linear combination of the columns in your second matrix, such that the correlation between the two linear combinations is maximized.

This can be done manually using eigenvectors and eigenvalues, but if you have the statistics toolbox, then Matlab has already got it packaged and ready to go for you. The function is called `canoncorr`, and the documentation is [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/canoncorr.html)

A brief example of the usage of this function follows:

```
%# Set up some example data
CovMat = randi(5, 4, 4) + 20 * eye(4); %# Build a random covariance matrix
CovMat = (1/2) * (CovMat + CovMat'); %# Ensure random covriance matrix is symmetrix
X = mvnrnd(zeros(500, 4), CovMat); %# Simulate data using multivariate Normal

%# Partition the data into two matrices
X1 = X(:, 1:2);
X2 = X(:, 3:4);

%# Find the canonical correlations of the two matrices
[A, B, r] = canoncorr(X1, X2);
```

The first canonical correlation is the first element of `r`, and the second canonical correlation is the second element of `r`.

The `canoncorr` function also has a lot of other outputs. I'm not sure I'm clever enough to provide a satisfactory yet concise explanation of them here so instead I'm going to be lame and recommend you read up on it in a multivariate analysis textbook - most multivariate analysis textbooks will have a full chapter dedicated to canonical correlations.

Finally, if you don't have the statistics toolbox, then a quick google revealed the following [FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5230-acape/content/acape.m) that claims to provide canonical correlation analysis - note, I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: +1 - you learn something new every day. This day, you are responsible for my learning ;)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, let's have a short try:

```
A = [1:20; rand(1,20)]'; % Generate some data...
```

The best way to examine a 2-dimensional relationship is by looking at the data plots:

```
plot(A(:,1), A(:,2), 'o') % In the random data you should not see some pattern...
```

If we really want to compute some correlation coefficients, we can do this with `corrcoef`, as you mentioned:

```
B = corrcoef(A)
ans =

    1.0000   -0.1350
   -0.1350    1.0000
```

Here, `B(1,1)` is the correlation between column 1 and column 1, `B(2,1)` between column 1 and column 2 (and vice versa, thus `B` is symmetric).

One may argue about the usefulness of such a measure in a two-dimensional context - in my opinion you usually gain more insights by looking at the plots.